# i am using pharo2.0 and i need to implement a dictionary where a symbol has to map but im not understanding how to implement it

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

So I want to implement a dictionary where I can map symbols say #xyz to some numeric value like 1. and given an input, I must be able to identify how many times #xyz will occur in an output.

I think I have to use the following syntax

```
Dictionary newFrom: {#xyz -> 1. #abc -> 2. #klm -> 3}
```

but I am unable to apply this concept in a program. How do you refer to a particular value key pair in small talk?

Suppose my code had to do something like

> 10 apples + 5 apples = 15 apples

or

> 10 apples + 5 oranges = 10 apples + 5 oranges

Then in some input function I would have to do something like:

//Forgive the pseudo c syntax I am new to small talk.

```
if (fruit1 == 1 && fruit2 == 1) //here #apples -> 1
    <br>resultFruit == apples.
<br>else
    <br>resultfruit == 0 //where 0 -> no change ie fruits are different.
```

how do you convert this into small talk code...

Any help is appreciated. If you could point me to an implementation of dictionary in any known project please do so so that I can see and understand how it is supposed to be written.

Answer (score 2):

The basic use of a dictionary is by calling at: or at:put:

Imagine you assign your dictionary to a variable:

`myDict := Dictionary newFrom: {#xyz -> 1. #abc -> 2. #klm -> 3}.`

then you can write

`myDict at: #xyz`

to read the entry `#xyz` (returns 1)

or you can store things in the dictionary by

`myDict at: #foo put: 123`

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the idea with dictionary, but regarding your example I'd suggest next strategy:

Create class `Fruits` which knows how many apples are in there and other fruits. Then create a DSL methods in `Integer` like `apples` and `oranges` that will return a new `Fruits` object with specified amount of fruits. Then create `+` and `=` methods in `Fruits`, so that you can combine fruits and compare them.

If I misunderstood your problem please let me know.